# Installing JBoss Tools plugin in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, jboss, eclipse-plugin, jboss-tools

I tried to install JBoss AS Tools in Eclipse (Indigo) and failed. I get error with this description:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>   session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.springsource.javax.jms,1.1.0

I searched web and only thing that worked for some is running **eclipse -clean** but not for me. I have also updated Eclipse to latest version. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 7):

To install JBoss Tools, start up Eclipse then:
Help > Install New Software... >
and add this URL:
http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/indigo/

--> If you have eclipse helios add this one:
http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/indigo/

You can also download Update Zips (Archived p2 Repos) for offline installation, but DO NOT UNPACK THEM into your Eclipse root or dropins folder! Next, install into Eclipse using

Help > Install New Software... > Add... > Archive...

http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/stable/3_2_GA.html

I hope this help you.