# JSF 2 eclipse and JBOSS Dev studio + JBOSS tool, how to create a .xhtml file?

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, jboss

I'm new to JSF so maybe it's a noob question.

1. In eclipse, I create a new JSF project.
2. After that, I open facex-config.xml, right click -> new view. Here, for every template I choose (html, xhtml, xhtml with xml syntax), eclipse always create a .jsp file.
3. Now if I try to use JSF 2 tags (like h:link or h:head or h:ajax, jBoss throw errors (and eclipse too)

I solved changing the extension to .xhtml and rewriting the header of the file like this:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:f="...." xmlns:h="...">
```

And with this, all works fine.

The question is: how to create this xhtml file from eclipse instead of manually write it? Isn't JBOSS dev studio supposed to help me? :)

ps:

eclipse: juno

jboss dev studio 6.0

jboss as 7.1.1 final

**EDIT:**
When the file is created from JBOSS dev studio (xhtml template) this is the result (test.jsp):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
    <h:link>test</h:link>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

I have to rename to .xhtml and remove the lines before !DOCTYPE[...] to get it working.
I'm asking what am I doing wrong with JBOSS dev studio...

Thanks.
D.

Comment: Is the project configured as JSF 2.x project or as JSF 1.x project? JSP was standard in JSF 1.x. Check *Project Facets* section in project's properties for details.

Comment: @BalusC, thank you for the reply. In project facets, JavaServer Faces is setted to 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should first install JBoss tools to be able to use JSF in your project [Install Jboss Tools in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926068/installing-jboss-tools-plugin-in-eclipse-indigo)

then from your eclipse create new web project and from configuration choose Java server faces v2 Project.

Comment: I have both JBOSS dev studio and tools installed. It seems that the project is JSF 1 but when I created I chose JSF 2 and in "project facets" I can get confirm of that. Thank you